# Why is this not too broad?

Tags: support, review-audits, needs-more-focus

Doing reviews, I came over this [How to stream media player from one Android phone to another over Wi-Fi or Wi-Fi hotspot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788750/how-to-stream-media-player-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wi-fi-or-wi-fi) Which I classified "too broad".

The automated system tells me "wrong"; because 5 upvotes already, and answers.

But I keep wondering: am I missing something, or can those 5 (now 3) upvotes be seen as "invalid" in this case?

Comment: Looks like in the Android tag everything gets a thumb-up, even when you throw cat-gifs at it...

Comment: Currently audits are chosen automatically from a pool of questions. The questions must be upvoted above a certain score, can have no downvotes or close votes, can not have had a recent bounty, etc. IIRC also none of the answers can have been downvoted, but that might be wishful thinking.

Comment: @rene Whats wrong with cat-gifs? That can **never** be wrong!

Comment: @GhostCat sorry I read "is that a mis-interpretation by the 5 upvoters ?" as "is that a mis-interpretation of the 5 upvotes?". No one will ever know what was going through the upvoters minds at the time they voted unless they tell us. And there's nothing that can be done about it except for correcting the action with further actions such as close voting and downvoting.

Comment: @TinyGiant Reworded; hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Any voting can be seen as invalid by someone somewhere. The fact is that we are allowed to vote however we see fit so long as it isn't fraudulent. The only thing that can be done about this is voting to close and downvoting as you see it. Failing one incorrect audit usually isn't an issue, but if you get a review ban from it, you can ask a moderator to review your history. They can and usually will lift a ban caused by invalid audit failures.

Comment: Funny thing ... I actually did a wrong review last week; and because I had this other one here some time ago; I am now banned for two weeks ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system is ***very* naive**. It has upvotes, no downvotes, no close votes and is recent? It's a known good audit! Some tags seems to generate this kind of situation more often that others. The solution? Vote like mad and use filters. When you see something that isn't [java] or that looks like a drunk wrote it, skip. BTW, every question in the LQRQ is an audit.

Comment: *"When you see something that isn't [java] or that looks like a drunk wrote it, skip."* Huh? Why would you skip things that look like a drunk wrote it? I agree that "Skip" is underused, but in obvious cases…you should make the obvious choice.

Comment: @CodyGray is a reference to a comment by Shog (to animuson) where he saw weird ass questions that he couldn't make sense because he didn't know about the subject at hand. To him they read like a drunk asking a question, since even when he could understand the words and what it was asked, to him it still was nonsense.

Comment: I perfectly understand how the *system* works. That was not my question. My question was: is my "assumption" about this question (it should be closed) correct? And it took me some time to figure that the sentence reads "if you see something that dosnt look like a drunk wrote it" ... I first got the impression to skip all drunk questions ...