# Does it make a difference if I flag for review bans on SO Meta or on ('main') Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Last week I didn't pay attention when I failed a test review on [lqp](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15243622) (I am still not sure if that answer is really "spam", or just "link only", but yes, "saying OK" was wrong.) Unfortunately, I had another review fail the week before, but as discussed here on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343568/why-is-this-not-too-broad), back then ***I*** was right, and *the system* was wrong.

OK, so I have those two fails and received a ban; but actually the first fail wasn't a "real one". So I flagged that [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343568/why-is-this-not-too-broad) posting and asked for moderator help. I thought it wouldn't make a difference whether I flagged the "failed" review answer on SO, or my Meta question around it.

But, that flag has sat there since Friday and nothing has happened. Now I am wondering:

would it have made a difference if I had flagged directly on 'main' SO?

And would it now be legitimate to withdraw on Meta and flag somewhere on 'main' instead?

Comment: Probably.  Flags are a lot slower on meta.  IMHO any mod flag you need that is not directly related to something on meta should be done on main.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Nathan [wisely sayeth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344283/does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-flag-on-meta-or-on-stackoverflow-for-review-bans#comment450144_344283):

> Flags are a lot slower on meta. IMHO any mod flag you need that is not directly related to something on meta should be done on main.

Meta flags aren't looked at nearly as often as ones on main are, and there are often a few meta flags that moderators simply don't have the tools to handle - so the blue signal doesn't tend to draw attention on meta.

On main, there are "only" 33 'other' flags active - which is pretty low, and we'll probably work through most of the current ones within a few days.

Comment: '"only"'? you jinxed it, now there's 100.